# I can't boot after Ubuntu installation

Tags: boot, grub2

I have just installed Ubuntu 13.04, yet I had problems getting into any of the systems after installation [I had Windows 7 installed before].

The problem is, that after installation and restart, I didn't get the option to boot Ubuntu, only previous Windows Vista [which I replaced with Ubuntu] and Windows 7. I was trying to repair the boot option via Windows's EasyBSD or whatever was it called, then after restart, I had two options - Windows Vista and Ubuntu. Neither worked - Vista has been deleted and replaced by Ubuntu and 'Ubuntu' option was somehow wrongly set.

Now, I have two systems installed and I cannot run neither of them, so I'm using LiveCD.
Is here anybody who'd tell me exactly what am I ought to do? I'm literally lost...

Thanks.

Edit: sudo fdisk -l output:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x7c12e647

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          63  1729975589   864987763+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda2      1935093760  1953521663     9213952    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3      1912696830  1929230335     8266753    5  Extended
Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda4      1729976320  1912694783    91359232   83  Linux
/dev/sda5      1912696832  1929230335     8266752   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Disk /dev/sdb: 7862 MB, 7862353920 bytes
37 heads, 37 sectors/track, 11217 cylinders, total 15356160 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xc3072e18

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        8064    15356159     7674048    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)

Disk /dev/sdc: 8053 MB, 8053063680 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 979 cylinders, total 15728640 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1   *        2048    15728639     7863296    b  W95 FAT32
```

Comment: Imro - you appear to have multiple accounts.  Please register one of these accounts and then click the contact-us link at the bottom of this page to request your other accounts are merged.  Once done you'll be able to edit your question again with further info.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall GRUB2. Hopefully your OSes are still there and something happend to GRUB... See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing

With the extra info you provided the commands should be

> sudo mount /dev/sda4 /mnt
>
> sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sda

The first one mounts your ubuntu file system and the second one repairs the GRUB installation.

Then reboot.

Comment: That's a bit complicated for me, I'd rather someone to tell me exactly what to do step by step if possible :/

Comment: Okay, can you do a sudo fdisk -l and post the output in your original post?

Comment: Alright, done :]

Comment: See my edit of the original answer...

Comment: Can you access sda1 and/or sda2 (which I assume are the windows partitions) from your Ubuntu installation at all?

Comment: @Imro if you can access both sda1 and sda2, is there any way you can determine on which of those your Win7 should be?!