# Unable to access Windows after Ubuntu and GRUB installation

Tags: grub2, windows

I've been trying to solve this for a while, even had a topic here: [I can't boot after Ubuntu installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/355976/i-cant-boot-after-ubuntu-installation/356002#356002)

Long story short, I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 7, replacing Windows Vista. Now, when I turn on my computer, I get to grub with two options: Ubuntu and Windows 7.

Ubuntu works well, but after I choose Windows 7, I get redirected to the Windows GRUB-like environment, where I can choose either Windows Vista or Ubuntu. Neither of them works.

Anybody knows what am I ought to do now? Maybe making the GRUB option Windows 7 turning on the Windows 7 straight away?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Boot form your Windows 7 CD and open a terminal. (Windows cmd.exe)
Now type the following command: `bootrec /FixMBR`. See if it worked. If not, use `bootrec /FixBoot`. This will overwrite GRUB! Now you can only boot Windows 7.
Now boot from Live Ubuntu and follow these steps:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt    #replace X by the partition where Ubuntu is installed
sudo grub-install /dev/sda --root-directory=/mnt
sudo reboot
```

Now you should have a new GRUB. NOTE: If you changed the `/etc/default/grub`, you may have to re-edit it, I don't know whether `grub-install` touches that one too.